# Polkadot.js ui displays orange branding for Kusama

Tags: polkadot-js, kusama

When connecting to my own RPC server the polkadot.js displays an orange branding.

https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss://ibp-rpc.metaspan.io/kusama#/explorer/node

[image]

It should just show the default branding. Can someone please let me know how to troubleshoot this?

Kusama on Dwellir is the same version, and displays the correct UI branding:

https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fkusama-rpc.dwellir.com#/explorer/node

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems if your endpoint is not in this list, you get the Orange branding now:

[image]